# Debug Geometry Shader in draw call DrawInstancedIndirect

Tags: debugging, directx-11, geometry-shader

My program is a rain particle system based on the compute shader for advancing rain drops and another rendering shader(vertex shader, geometry shader, pixel shader) for rendering the advanced rain drops.

I use the draw call: DrawInstancedIndirect to apply the results from the Compute Shader to the rendering step.

My problem is in the rendering step, at the Geometry shader, where I'm trying to draw a billboard for each rain drop. If I just draw a normal regtangle, it render well, and when I change to a billboard, nothing is in the render target. I'm trying to find a way to debug this geometry shader. I used the following tools for debugging geometry shader, but thet do work out for me.

Graphics Debugger in VS2012. It seems that this tool do not support draw call: DrawInstancedIndirect.

GPU PeftStudio. It support vertex, pixel shader, but not Geometry shader. I tried to pass out the immediate values from geometry shader to pixel shaders for seeing them, and they are all zero. But I need to dig into geometry shader for finding out the error.

Nsight by NVDIA. My graphics card is 720M, and it's so sad that Nsight only supports from 730M. May be it is the reason the shader list is empty why I am in the debugging process.

I'm desperated now, and seeing no way to find out the problem. I hope you could suggest me a way to debug this geometry shader. Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried PIX For Windows in the June 2010 Direct SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [RenderDoc](http://cryengine.com/renderdoc) by Crytek, it's really easy to use and you can monitor every buffers in every stages.

Comment: Unfortunately, currently renderdoc does not support geometry shader debugging
```https://renderdoc.org/docs/how/how_debug_shader.html```